# how to compile and start a Java undertow HTTP server using command line

Tags: java, undertow

I have the following project folder setup for a simple Java undertow HTTP server:

```
- HelloWorldServer.java

- build

- lib
```

I downloaded XNIO and JBOSS-Logging into lib.  I made sure I downloaded the right distributions by letting Gradle download the dependencies.  But I'm trying to understand more by running things manually so I copy the jar files into the lib folder.

My `HelloWorldServer.java` looks like this:

```
import io.undertow.Undertow;
import io.undertow.util.*;


public class HelloWorldServer {
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
                              .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
                              .setHandler(exchange -> {
                                  exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                                  exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");
                              }).build();
    server.start();
    }
}
```

Then I go to my folder root and run the following command:

```
javac -cp "lib/*" -d build HelloWorldServer.java
```

Now that I've compiled the application, how do I run it from terminal?

EDIT: the content of my `lib` directory is as follows:

```
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar // i believe thats not needed, but leave it anyway
jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar
undertow-core-2.0.0.Alpha1.jar
xnio-api-3.3.6.Final.jar
xnio-nio-3.3.6.Final.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since with -d flag you asked java compiler to generate class files inside build directory.So you need to run like this :

```
java -cp "build/:lib/*" HelloWorldServer
```

Comment: This outputs the following: `Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorldServer   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorldServer`

Comment: @jimmyt Please try updated command now, I have tested in my local and is working fine.

Comment: `java -cp "lib/*"` doesn't work.  Each dependency must be listed separately and separated by a colon for it to work.

Comment: Who said that you need to list them separately, the wildcard `*` is used to avoid adding them separately.